# How to solve "cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'"

Tags: python, opencv, cvzone

I'm learning how to use opencv, but I'm running into this problem.

```
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture("https://192.168.178.49:8080/video")
detector = HandDetector(maxHands=1, detectionCon=0.7)

while True:
    success, img= cap.read()
    
    img = detector.findHands(img) 
    
    cv2.imshow("AI", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Results in this error:

```
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programming\Arm Code\testhandai.py", line 13, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("AI", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imshow'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - mat is not a numerical tuple
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

I'm using Python 3.8 64-bit and the latest version for all the packages.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output of `detector.findHands(img)` is a tuple. You should give second element of it as input to `cv2.imshow()`:

```
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture("https://192.168.178.49:8080/video")
detector = HandDetector(maxHands=1, detectionCon=0.7)

while True:
    success, img= cap.read()
    
    img = detector.findHands(img) 
    
    cv2.imshow("AI", img[1])
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In place of this:

```
img = detector.findHands(img)
```

use this:

```
_ , img = detector.findHands(img)
```

Note:
The `detector.findHands(img)` returns two variables `allHands` and `img`.
Due to this we get the error.
Now we assigned `allHands` to `some_var` and `img` to `img`, so we don't get a error.

Answer (score 0):

mediapipe added a new variable, which screw up the handtracking and pose estimation call complexity and model_complexity.  See below.

Now Im working on the face detection, and the module work perfect, but when I pull it into a different it fails.

for handtracking module

```
def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, complexity = 1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
    self.mode = mode
    self.maxHands = maxHands
    self.complexity = complexity
    self.detectionCon = detectionCon
    self.trackCon = trackCon
    self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
    self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.complexity,
                                    self.detectionCon, self.trackCon, )
```

for the post esitimation module:

```py
def __init__(self, mode = False, model_complexity = 1, smooth = True,
                    enable_segmentation = False, smooth_segmentation = True, min_detection_confidence = 0.5,
                    min_tracking_confidence = 0.5):
    self.mode = mode
    self.model_complexity = model_complexity
    self.smooth = smooth
    self.enable_segmentation = enable_segmentation
    self.smooth_segmentation = smooth_segmentation
    self.detectionCon = min_detection_confidence
    self.trackCon = min_tracking_confidence
    self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    self.mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
    self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(self.mode, self.model_complexity, self.smooth, self.enable_segmentation,
                                 self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go in your source-code editor and

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

And then reinstall it

```
pip install opencv-python
```

I was having same error and this worked for me